# Can't change encapsulated class in angular

Tags: css, angular

Angular creates a div with a class container and put inside my component html. Is it possible to change that class to a container-fluid ? I read that angular use encapsulation but im not sure where can I find that div and if its even possible to change it's class.

[image]

Comment: Can you show you code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the html file who has that div in **src/app/app.component.html** check it and change the class that you want. hope that help